# Uncaught TypeError: Fragment.load is not a function

Tags: sapui5, amd

The code below has been copied from UI5 Demo Kit but while I run it, the console is showing the error message that the function `Fragment.load` is not a function. Please suggest any alternative or highlight issue if any.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/m/MessageToast",
  "sap/ui/model/Filter",
  "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/m/MessageToast",
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
], function(Controller, MessageToast, Filter, FilterOperator, JSONModel, Fragment) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("Workspace.controller.HelloPanel", {
    onInit: function() {
      var plant = {
        pid: "",
        ptype: "",
        pdesc: "",
        psite: "",
        pstatus: "",
        passigned: "",
        pattach: ""
      };
      var oModel1 = new JSONModel(plant);
      this.getView().setModel(oModel1, "SUP");
    },

    onOpenDialog: function() {
      var oView = this.getView();
      if (!this.byId("helloDialog")) {
        Fragment.load({
          id: oView.getId(),
          name: "Workspace.view.HelloDialog",
          controller: this
        }).then(function(oDialog) {
          // connect dialog to the root view of this component (models, lifecycle)
          oView.addDependent(oDialog);
          oDialog.open();
        });
      } else {
        this.byId("helloDialog").open();
      }
    },

    onCloseDialog: function() {
      this.byId("helloDialog").close();
    },

  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Reason 1: mismatch of dependencies and callback parameters

When calling `sap.ui.define` or `sap.ui.require`, you need to ensure that the declared *dependencies* and the callback *parameters* are listed in the **same order:**

```js
sap.ui.define([ // list of dependencies
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", // 1st
  "sap/m/MessageToast", // 2nd
  // ...
], function (Controller/*1st*/, MessageToast/*2nd, ...*/) {
  // ...
});
```

In the question above, for example, we can see that `"sap/m/MessageToast"` is accidentally **required twice**, resulting in a mismatch with the list of callback parameters. Remove the 2nd `"sap/m/MessageToast"` from the dependency list. Otherwise, you're trying to call `.load()` from the MessageToast, hence the error.

### Reason 2: the method was introduced in later versions

If you're getting the same error, despite having the correct dependency order, keep in mind that UI5 introduced [`Fragment.load`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Fragment#methods/sap.ui.core.Fragment.load) first in **1.58**.

To see which UI5 version the app is actually running with, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

---

### Recommendation

If the application's target UI5 version is 1.93 or higher, favor the **built-in Controller API `loadFragment`** over calling `Fragment.load`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541325/5846045