# Fragment won't open due to the error "Cannot instantiate object: 'new' is missing!"

Tags: sapui5, amd

Unfortunately, my fragment page won't open.
Trying to open a select dialogue (fragment with table) after a button press.

Here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPq8A.png):

> formatter function sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayoutWithOneColumnStart.controller.Formatter not found!
>
> ---
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot instantiate object: "new" is missing!
>     at constructor (Object-dbg.js:39:11)
>     at constructor (EventProvider-dbg.js:29:14)
>     at constructor (ManagedObject-dbg.js:464:17)
>     at constructor (Fragment-dbg.js:122:17)
>     at f._configDialog (DetailDetail.controller.js?eval:120:4)
>     at f.eval (DetailDetail.controller.js?eval:84:10)

I have a `Formatter` in my project folder. The property `_pDialog` seems to be empty, although my view clearly exists.

The error is in the method `handleTableSelectDialogPress`.

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
    "sap/m/MessageToast",
    "./Formatter",
    "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
    "sap/ui/model/Filter",
    "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/core/syncStyleClass",
], function(JSONModel, Controller, Fragment, MessageToast, FilterOperator, syncStyleClass) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayoutWithOneColumnStart.controller.DetailDetail", {
        // ...,

        handleTableSelectDialogPress: function(oEvent) {
            var oButton = oEvent.getSource(),
                oView = this.getView();
            if (!this._pDialog) {
                this._pDialog = Fragment.load({
                    id: oView.getId(),
                    name: "sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayoutWithOneColumnStart.view.Dialog",
                    controller: this
                }).then(function(oDialog) {
                    oView.addDependent(oDialog);
                    return oDialog;
                });
            }

            this._pDialog.then(function(oDialog) {
                this._configDialog(oButton, oDialog);
                oDialog.open();
            }.bind(this));
        },

        _configDialog: function(oButton, oDialog) {
            // ...
            syncStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact", this.getView(), oDialog);
        },

        // ...
    });
});
```

This is my view:

```xml
<mvc:View displayBlock="true" controllerName="sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayoutWithOneColumnStart.controller.DetailDetail" height="100%" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"   xmlns="sap.f" xmlns:m="sap.m">
    <DynamicPage toggleHeaderOnTitleClick="false">
        <!-- ... -->
        <content>
            <m:Button
                class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"
                text="Show Table Select Dialog"
                press=".handleTableSelectDialogPress"
                ariaHasPopup="Dialog" />
        </content>
    </DynamicPage>
</mvc:View>
```

This is my Fragment:

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m">
    <TableSelectDialog id="myDialog"
        title="Select Product"
        search=".handleSearch"
        confirm=".handleClose"
        cancel=".handleClose"
        items="{
            path: '/ProductCollection',
            sorter: {
                path: 'Name',
                descending: false
            }
        }">
        <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle">
            <!-- ... -->
        </ColumnListItem>
        <columns>
            <!-- ... -->
        </columns>
    </TableSelectDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

This is my project folder:

[image: my SAPUI5 project folder]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Fragment.load is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55287847/uncaught-typeerror-fragment-load-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **mismatch** of the required dependencies in the array with the callback parameters of the controller factory function:

> ```js
> sap.ui.define([
>   "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
>   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
>   "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
>   "sap/m/MessageToast",
>   "./Formatter", // <-- here you required Formatter
>   "sap/ui/core/Fragment", // <-- required Fragment (again)
>   "sap/ui/model/Filter",
>   "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator",
>   "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel", // <-- required JSONModel (again)
>   "sap/ui/core/syncStyleClass",
> ], /*factory*/function(JSONModel, Controller, Fragment, MessageToast, FilterOperator/*<-- Formatter */, syncStyleClass/*<-- Fragment */) {/* ... */});
> ```

Consequently, the parameter `syncStyleClass` is **not** the module `sap/ui/core/syncStyleClass` but `sap/ui/core/Fragment`! And **calling `Fragment()` without `new`** results in the [error *`"new" is missing!`*](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/bd5f8f6cdcd080e31751dfb40bcccaa5e5e0ebe4/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/Object.js#L34-L39).

The name of the function parameters is not relevant to the framework. Important is the correct order of those parameters according to the list of dependencies. From the [API reference of `sap.ui.define`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui#methods/sap.ui.define):

> The module export of each dependency module will be provided as a parameter to a factory function, the **order of the parameters will match the order of the modules in the dependencies array**.

The same rule applies to `sap.ui.require`.